# See HTTPS POST/GET values

Tags: php, http, https

I know that there are lots of software/addons out there that can show you the POST/GET values whenever you do an HTTP request.

My question is, do the POST/GET values still appear when my site is using HTTPS (SSL) ?

Assume there is a proxy between my browser and the server, will it be able to see my POST/GET when I use https ?

What proxies is recommended to use for such a scenario testing ?

Comment: not a clear question any traffic using https is encrypted between users browser and your server

Comment: @Dagon the question is : do the POST/GET values still appear if intercepted when my site is using HTTPS (SSL) ? and the interceptor can use them for replay attack etc..

Comment: POST/GET values are encrypted when using https, which is the point of using it to stop man in the middle attacks.

Answer (score 1):

SSL is a communication protocol between the client browser and the server (i.e. Apache, nginx, etc). It doesn't change the data communicated (i.e. `$_GET` and `$_POST`), it changes how that data is transmitted.

Proxies don't change this either. A proxy simply acts as a communication agent between the server and client.